# Difference between Magento Composer install and release install

Tags: magento2, installation, composer

What are the differences between the various Magento installs?

I installed it using the released code from github(v2.3.0.zip) and I installed it using

```
composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition <install-directory-name>
```

The composer install has a lot more options on the admin end.

Which is the preferred installation type?